# Manipulating two characters in url with purrr package for scraping pupose

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, purrr

I'm having difficulties writing a scrape function with the `purrr` package (first time). I want to scrape multiple pages by changing two characters of the designated url. The following code works for only one season of football players data.

```
page_func <- function(page) {

  cat(".")

  df <- read_html(paste0("http://www.voetbal.com/spelerslijst/ned-eredivisie-2017-2018/nach-name/", 
                         page)) %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    as.tbl() %>%
    select(Speler, Team, Geboren, Lengte, Positie) %>%
    add_column(seizoen = "2017-2018")

}

raw_seizoen_17_18 <- map_df(1:11, page_func)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 541 x 6
   Speler           Team             Geboren    Lengte Positie seizoen  
   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    
 1 Amir Absalem     FC Groningen     19.06.1997 ???    VD      2017-2018
 2 Asumah Abubakar  Willem II        10.05.1997 183 cm AV      2017-2018
 3 Ragnar Ache      Sparta Rotterdam 28.07.1998 182 cm AV      2017-2018
 4 Marouane Afaker  SBV Excelsior    09.05.1999 ???    AV      2017-2018
 5 Gor Agbaljan     Heracles Almelo  25.04.1997 183 cm MV      2017-2018
 6 Thomas Agyepong  NAC Breda        10.10.1995 168 cm AV      2017-2018
```

Now I want to scrape all seasons from `1956-1957` untill `2017-2018` in one function, but I can't yet figure out how to manipulate these two variables with `purrr`.

```
page_season_func <- function(seizoen, page) {

  cat(".")

  df <- read_html(paste0("http://www.voetbal.com/spelerslijst/ned-eredivisie-", 
                         seizoen, 
                         "/nach-name/", 
                         page)) %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    as.tbl() %>%
    select(Speler, Team, Geboren, Lengte, Positie) %>%
    add_column(year = seizoen)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seasons <- 
  1956:2017 %>% 
  paste(., . + 1, sep = "-")

res <- 
  cross2(seasons, 1:11) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  pmap_df(page_season_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map2_dfr`, with the `.id` tag to specify the year in your output:

```
page_span <- 1:11
year_span <- 1956:1958
years <- sort(rep(year_span, length(page_span)))
names(years) <- years # need to name years for .id to work
pages <- rep(page_span, length(year_span))
map2_dfr(years, pages, page_season_func, .id="year")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  year  Speler             Team          Geboren   Lengte Positie
  <chr> <chr>              <chr>         <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  
1 1956  Sjeng Adang        Roda JC Kerk… 04.07.19… ???    MV     
2 1956  Wim Anderiesen jr. AFC Ajax      02.09.19… ???    VD     
3 1956  Wim Andriesen      AFC Ajax      09.02.19… ???    MV     
4 1956  Aad Bak            Feyenoord     18.06.19… ???    MV     
5 1956  Huub Bisschops     Roda JC Kerk… 22.01.19… ???    AV     
6 1956  Wim Bleijenberg    AFC Ajax      05.11.19… ???    AV
```

A couple of changes to `page_season_func()`:

- `seizoen2` is created, which makes the `y1-y2` format from `y1` as input
- no need to add a `year` column, now that you can use `map2_dfr`'s `.id` argument

  ```
  page_season_func <- function(seizoen, page) {
    cat(".")
    seizoen2 <- paste(seizoen, seizoen+1, sep="-")
    df <- read_html(paste0("http://www.voetbal.com/spelerslijst/ned-eredivisie-", 
                           seizoen2, 
                           "/nach-name/", 
                           page)) %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      html_table(fill=TRUE) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      as.tbl() %>%
      select(Speler, Team, Geboren, Lengte, Positie)
  }
  ```